# Compiling java test issue

Tags: jakarta-ee

I get this error when I compile my Test in java-
`package org.mockito does not exist` 
and

`class Mock does not exist`

Though the `org` package has been imported.

What is the specific reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

It means the JARs containing those classes aren't in your test CLASSPATH.  Add them and it'll work.

`import` has nothing at all to do with loading classes.  All it does is save you typing: you can refer to `java.lang.String` as `String` in your code.

Comment: How do I add it to the test classpath? I copy pasted the JAR into projectname/client/target/dependancy . The name of the JAR file is mockito-all-1.9.0.jar. I also added this to the POM file         <!-- Testing -->
  <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <mockito.version>1.9.0</mockito.version>

Comment: I don't know what all that stuff is about.  You need to learn how to set CLASSPATH when you compile with javac.exe and run with java.exe.  It's the -classpath option for both.  Add all your JARs to it.